# Using strings as comments in python

Tags: python

I'm currently reading python code that is using strings as comments. For example, here's a function

```
def xyz(x):
    """This is a function that does a thing.
    Pretty cool, right?"""
    return 0
```

What's the point of using strings as comments? It seems really strange. The code compiles, but it's very confusing.

Comment: Its noT string comments! Its basically `multi line` comments !

Comment: It's called a `docstring` and it is interpreted by python's help/documentation system, try `help(xyz)`. Usually you would describe the types of arguments this function takes and what to expect as a return.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docstring

Comment: It seems strange to me that the return has a semi-colon

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm still getting used to the syntax :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"""This is a function that does a thing.
Pretty cool, right?"""
```

This is called [docstring](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/manual-docstring.html). Python documentation strings (or docstrings) provide a convenient way of associating documentation with Python modules, functions, classes, and methods.

**Example**

Docstrings can be accessed from the interpreter and from Python programs using the `__doc__` attribute:

```
print(xyz.__doc__)
```

It outputs:

```
This is a function that does a thing.
    Pretty cool, right?
```

Another usage:

```
from pydoc import help
print(help(xyz))
```

It outputs:

```
Help on function xyz in module __main__:

xyz(x)
    This is a function that does a thing.
    Pretty cool, right?
```

Answer (score 2):

They're called [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring), and they're used for documenting your code. Tools and builtins like `help()` also inspect docstrings, so they're not just for readers of the code, but also users of your code.

Comment: I didn't know that `help()` was a function, thank you, that's helpful.